# Elementwise multiplication of pandas Dataframes with different indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'month':['jun', 'jul', 'aug'],'a':[3,4,5], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[4,5,5]}).set_index('month')

       a  b  c
month         
jun    3  2  4
jul    4  3  5
aug    5  4  5
```

and

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'year':[2009,2009,2009, 2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011],'month':['jun', 'jul', 'aug','jun', 'jul', 'aug','jun', 'jul', 'aug'],'a':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'c':[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]}).set_index('year')

     month  a  b  c
year               
2009   jun  2  1  3
2009   jul  2  2  3
2009   aug  2  3  3
2010   jun  2  4  3
2010   jul  2  5  3
2010   aug  2  6  3
2011   jun  2  7  3
2011   jul  2  8  3
2011   aug  2  9  3
```

I would like to multiply df2's elements with df1's according to the months. Is there quick way to do it?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by `month`s converted to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
:

```
df = df2.set_index('month', append=True).mul(df1, level=1).reset_index(level=1)
print (df)
     month   a   b   c
year                  
2009   jun   6   2  12
2009   jul   8   6  15
2009   aug  10  12  15
2010   jun   6   8  12
2010   jul   8  15  15
2010   aug  10  24  15
2011   jun   6  14  12
2011   jul   8  24  15
2011   aug  10  36  15
```